# PhpMyAdmin/MySQL: Missing "id=" after WHERE keyword when deleting via user interface?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am using **PhpMyAdmin 4.5.4.1** and **MySql 5.7.10** to work on a school project.

PhpMyAdmin and MySql run under **Mac OS X El Captain.**

Everything works just fine except I am unable to delete/edit/etc. with data entries.

The screenshot here clearly shows that after "WHERE" keyword, "id=x" is missing.

For my entity, "id" is set to be the primary key's name.

I used default settings to set up MySQL database and PhpMyAdmin.

[image: A screenshot]

Comment: How are you trying to delete? Using the User Interface or by running a sql command?

Comment: Please provide the SQL command

Comment: Using User Interface. I am talking about clicking buttons. I clicked the delete button and it generated a wrong delete mysql command as demonstrated above

Comment: What operating system is MySQL running under? Can you verify the value of the variable `lower_case_table_names` (which is visible under the "Variables" tab of the main page)?

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same problem. My System is MAcOS El Capitan as well and MYSQL 5.6.19. I use the newest stable version of PhpMyAdmin 4.6.4 and get the same error Message. Whenever I use an older Version of phpmyadmin (in my case 3.5.7) it is working with no problems at all. So far I could narrow it down to a Problem with the variable "where_clause", which is always empty. 
The strangest thing is, that all tables that do not have an Upper case in its name work fine. Just those with an Upper Case won't work.

Comment: This is not an answer.